# Python: Regex is not good for re.search (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group')

Tags: python, regex

**In my html file I have this line:**

```
<div class="color-black mt-lg-0" id="hidden">, in</div>
<a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/leadership-pro.html" title="View all articles from Leadership Pro" class="color-green font-weight-600 mx-1" id="hidden">Leadership Pro</a>
```

**I use this regex** `^\s*<a href="(.*?)" title="View` i**n order to find this link** `https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/leadership-pro.html`

In notepad++ the regex search is ok !

The problem is in Python.

**FIND: (on line 18)**

`b_content = re.search('^\s*<a href="(.*?)" title="View', new_file_content).group(1)`

**REPLACE:**

`old_file_content = re.sub(', in <a href="(.*?)" title="Vezi', f', in <a href="{b_content}" title="Vezi', old_file_content)`

Gives me this error on `re.search` line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 18, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I, also, try to change that line with:

`b_content = re.match(r'^\s*<a href="(.*?)" title="View', new_file_content).group(1)`

but I get the same error

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and belong on [so].

Answer (score -1):

**REPLACE THOSE 2 lines of code with this:**

```
import re

b_content = re.match(r'^\s*<a href="(.*?)" title="View', new_file_content)
if b_content is not None:
    b_content = b_content.group(1)
else:
    b_content = "No match found"
```

**OR another way:**

```
import re

match = re.search('^\s*<a href="(.*?)" title="View', new_file_content)
if match is not None:
    b_content = match.group(1)
    old_file_content = re.sub(', in <a href="(.*?)" title="Vezi', f', in <a href="{b_content}" title="Vezi', old_file_content)
else:
    print("No match found")
```

**Or, you can use re.MULTILINE**

```
import re

match = re.search('^\s*<a href="(.*?)" title="View', new_file_content, re.MULTILINE)
if match is not None:
    b_content = match.group(1)
    old_file_content = re.sub(', in <a href="([^"]*)" title="Vezi', f', in <a href="{b_content}" title="Vezi', old_file_content)
else:
    print("No match found")
```

**OR, THE BEST:**

```
import re

# Citește conținutul fișierului new-file.html
with open('c:/Folder7/new-file.html', 'r') as file:
    first_code = file.read()

# Citește conținutul fișierului old-file.html
with open('c:/Folder7/old-file.html', 'r') as file:
    second_code = file.read()

# Extrage URL-ul din first_code
match = re.search('<a href="(.*?)" title="View all articles', first_code)
if match is not None:
    url = match.group(1)
    # Înlocuiește URL-ul în second_code
    second_code = re.sub(', in <a href=".*?" title="Vezi toate', f', in <a href="{url}" title="Vezi toate', second_code)

    # Scrie conținutul modificat înapoi în old-file.html
    with open('c:/Folder7/old-file.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(second_code)
else:
    print("No match found")
```

**OR USE BeautifulSoup:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
 
html = '''\
<div class="color-black mt-lg-0" id="hidden">, in</div>
<a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/leadership-pro.html" title="View all articles from Leadership Pro" class="color-green font-weight-600 mx-1" id="hidden">Leadership Pro</a>
'''
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('a').get('href')
print(link)
```